# How to use joblib parallelbackend for fitting LightGBM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dask, joblib, lightgbm

I am developing a model with 2M rows but the pandas dataframe is throwing memory error while reading the file. I am using python 3.6
I used dask dataframe to read the file and tried to use scikit learn using joblib to train the model. Code worked fine but with more waiting time, high memory and cpu usage impacting other running jobs. Code below for the reference.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
import joblib
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import lightgbm as lgb
client = Client(processes=False)
#read data and split
train_data= dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/my-parquet-data')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data.loc[:,X],
                                                    train_data.loc[:,y],
                                                    test_size=0.20,
                                                    random_state=42)
estimator= lgb.LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt',n_jobs=-1, silent=True, importance_type='gain'
objective='binary','is_unbalance': True)

param_grid = {
'learning_rate': [0.7, 0.1, 0.15],
'n_estimators': [150, 200, 250],
'max_depth': [3,4,5]
}
gbm = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, cv=3)
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
# Will this use each chunk to train data. So parallel processing and boosting will work fine here? Referense on [joblib][1]
     gbm.fit(X_train, y_train,
     eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
     eval_metric='logloss',
     early_stopping_rounds=20)
#AUC and Curve
#Any suggestions to avoid compute and still able to get auc and plot the curve?
y_test=test_y.compute().ravel()
prd_test = gbm.predict_proba(X)[:,1].compute() 
#for curve;
fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_test, prd_test )
auc_ = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

Could anyone please help me with:

1) Is parallel-backend right way to train boosting tree? Am I missing any theory here such as if parallel processing and boosting go right here?. Will this take care of all the partitions at the backend i.e. read all to fit the model.

2)Optimize the code to run fast and consume less memory. Any parameters to the estimator. I have used n_job=-1 for parallel run

3) How to calculate ROC/AUC  without using compute (put arrays in-memory)?

4) Is there any way to plot AUC without using compute and put arrays in-memory.

Do I need the `.persist()` anywhere in between to speed up the process? I am using 3 workers with 2 cores each
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think the `with joblib.parallel_backend('dask')` is likely to have any effect here.  I don't think that lightgbm uses joblib internally.

Comment: @TomAugspurger : few questions. 1) So I can directly use scikit learn procedures (light gbm here) and pass on dask dataframe to fit and test model?   2) By any chance do you know by when `dask_lightgbm.core` will have its own page on  ml.dask.org similar to XGBoost https://ml.dask.org/xgboost.html.  Could you please suggest/share the best way to train scikit lightgbm using dask dataframe.   Also, is there way to find df.shape0 quickly. I am using df.persist(), len(df.index) and is time consuming task. how to release memory after using persist()? df.persist()

Comment: @TomAugspurger:  Hi Tom, could you please share some insights on how I can use dask dataframe to fit  scikitlearn Lightgbm Classifier. Also after client.persist(df), can I reduce memory usage by using client.restart(). I note that sometime gc.collect use more CPU usage.. Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1) Your dask parallel backend should indeed work. This should make sure that model fitting operations are distributed across your machines. LightGBM is able to run on all cores for each machine with `n_jobs=-1`,

2) You could try and reduce the features space by using SVC or PCA to reduce dimensionality of your data. I would also advise you to reconsider your search space. Here is a great wiki page of how to tune a LightGBM model https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Parameters-Tuning.rst. Another option for you is to use spark https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/blob/master/docs/lightgbm.md. Lastly, you could try running randomizedsearchCV as that often does find a very good solution compared to exhaustive grid search, (you can then expand your search space accordingly)

I would also advise you to not tune the `n_estimators` parameter when using early stopping. Simply set it to for example 5000, lightgbm will stop when the score does not improve for `early_stopping_rounds=20` as you've specified.

I'm not sure what you mean with 3) and 4)

Comment: Thankyou @mikkelam for your answer. Yes,  I will update it to RandomCV and n_estimator to 500. I am looking for trees count < 200 ). I have a preference of scikit learn as compared to spark ml. Later is not much documented. or vetted.  For 3) and 4) : As you can see I am using Dask dataframe for training the model. Predicted output is dask array which requires `.compute()` to bring it in memory and pass it to sklearn functions to calculate ROC. I am trying to avoid arrays of length 1.5M

Comment: Ah got it. Perhaps you could compute ROC individually on each worker u have and then avg all your intermediate ROC values.

Comment: When I am using .compute() to get an array, I am able to calculate ROC using scikit learn function but this increases memory % to >90%. even after deleting redt_test or y_test. I am not able to reduce the memory usage (tried gc.collect)     Memory percent is calculated as : process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.memory_percent(). Any insights on how to reduce % memory after the use of prd_test = gbm.predict_proba(X)[:,1].compute(). Thankyou again!!